# FrameLayout with two includes only set correctly the first one. Why?

Tags: android, layout

I have a ScollView Layout with a FrameLayout that includes two different layouts. If some condition is met, I set one or the other as visible.
dialog_interface_login.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:font="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/color_white"
android:orientation="vertical">


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <include layout="@layout/landing_login_view"/>
    <include layout="@layout/mobile_login_view"/>
</FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My class:

```
final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_interface_login, container, false);
    View mobileLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.mobile_root_view);
    View landingLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.landing_root_view);
    if (landingLogin) {
        mobileLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        landingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mobileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        landingLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

Inside theese layouts that was set on the include, I have another include:
landing_login_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:font="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/landing_root_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/color_white"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/twenty_eight_dp"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/twenty_eight_dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

...

<include layout="@layout/sms_login"/>

...
</LinearLayout>
```

And mobile_login_view.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:font="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/mobile_root_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/color_white"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/twenty_eight_dp"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/twenty_eight_dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

...

<include layout="@layout/sms_login"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my sms_login.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:font="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/color_white"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fifty_six_dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/twelve_dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_white_enabled">

    <br.com.fs.fslogin.ui.support.views.GothamEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_phone_number"
        style="@style/AppTheme.RectangularEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/hint_enter_phone"
        android:inputType="number|none"
        android:maxLength="11"
        android:textColorHint="@color/task_done_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen_sp"
        font:name="@string/font_gotham_medium" />

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/dialog_error_phone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/thirty_two_dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/twelve_dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_warning_phone"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/eight_dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/eight_dp"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_error_phone_red" />

    <br.com.fs.fslogin.ui.support.views.GothamTextView
        android:id="@+id/error_phone_output"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/two_sp"
        android:textColor="@color/error_login_phone_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fourteen_sp"
        font:name="@string/font_gotham_medium" />

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/btn_sms_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/fifty_six_dp"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_login_vivo_purple">

    <br.com.fs.fslogin.ui.support.views.GothamButton
        style="@style/AppTheme.RectangularButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@null"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/btn_login"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/eighteen_sp"
        font:name="@string/font_gotham_bold" />
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Programmatically, I set some behaviors, such as a mask for the phone field etc.
But these behaviors that are programmatically configured in sms_login.xml will only occur if the layout is set first in my dialog_interface_login.xml. I have the same include, with the same information, but only works on the first one that is defined at ContainerLayout. Even the onclick event does not trigger.

Do you have any idea why? Is it possible to define two different includes?

----- Edited -----
Including some actions done

```
v.findViewById(R.id.btn_sms_login).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (phoneWatcher.isPhoneNumberValid()) {
                String phoneNumber = etPhoneNumber.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\D+", "");
                onSuccessClick.OnSuccess(phoneNumber);
                LoginInterfaceVivoSyncDialog.this.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please show an example of what you are trying to do in your code with the Views from sms_login.xml

Comment: @0X0nosugar done

Comment: Hello, it is can help for future, I had same problem, fix it to apply `view1.isVisible = state.showView1`, where after use `post`, `view1.post { view2.isVisible = !state.showView1`. It is correctly in case, where view2 call after view1 and view 2 is biggest then view1. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> Do you have any idea why?

This happens because `findViewById(R.id.xyz)` returns the first `View` which has the requested attribute `android:id="@+id/R.id.xyz"`.

Quoting from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#findviewbyid) on View:

> Finds the first descendant view with the given ID, the view itself if the ID matches getId(), or null if the ID is invalid (< 0) or there is no matching view in the hierarchy.

To access the correct `View`, you'll have to use some property which makes it unique. In your case, for example the value `R.id.et_phone_number` can be found twice in the `FrameLayout`. But if you write

```
View myView = mobileLayout.findViewById(R.id.et_phone_number);
```

then there will be just one child `View` of *mobileLayout* with the requested id.

Your code snippet can be changed as follows:

```
final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_interface_login, container, false);
    View mobileLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.mobile_root_view);
    View landingLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.landing_root_view);
    if (landingLogin) {
        mobileLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        landingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mobileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        landingLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    setupViewGroup(mobileLayout);
    setupViewGroup(landingLayout);
```

The method `setupViewGroup(View layout)` should look like this:

```
private void setupViewGroup(View layout)
{
    final EditText etPhoneNumber = layout.findViewById(R.id.et_phone_number);
    layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_sms_login).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (phoneWatcher.isPhoneNumberValid()) {
                String phoneNumber = etPhoneNumber.getText().toString().replaceAll("\\D+", "");
                // ...
            }
        }
    });
}
```

By calling `findViewById()` on *layout* you will get the desired child `View`s of the `ViewGroup`s which were added by using `<include .../>`

Comment: But that's why i'm using an include. I have a single piece of code, that i need to use in two separate places.

Comment: You did not show any of your code so I can't tell you how exactly to fix it. But I'm sure it's possible, e.g. by putting it all in some method and passing the root (mobile or landing) in as parameter

Answer (score 0):

- You should use `Visibility.GONE` instead of `INVISIBLE`
- You can directly assign id to include block why you made two extra different layouts to give just an id.
- I was shocked to see `@dimen/twelve_dp` (**really shocked**). What is use of `dimens.xml` if you are writing `twelve_dp` there. You can directly write `12dp`. It should be generic like `space_small` or `space_large` or `text_size_small`.
- Also removed some extra wrapping layouts from your xml.

**dialog_interface_login.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/color_white"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/landing_root_view"
            layout="@layout/sms_login" />
        <include
            android:id="@+id/mobile_root_view"
            layout="@layout/sms_login" />

    </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and

```
final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_interface_login, container, false);
    View mobileLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.mobile_root_view);
    View landingLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.landing_root_view);
    if (landingLogin) {
        mobileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        landingLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        mobileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        landingLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

**sms_login.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:font="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/color_white"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <br.com.fs.fslogin.ui.support.views.GothamEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_phone_number"
        style="@style/AppTheme.RectangularEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fifty_six_dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/twelve_dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_white_enabled"
        android:digits="0123456789"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/hint_enter_phone"
        android:inputType="number|none"
        android:maxLength="11"
        android:textColorHint="@color/task_done_color"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sixteen_sp"
        font:name="@string/font_gotham_medium" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_error_phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/thirty_two_dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/twelve_dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_warning_phone"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/eight_dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/eight_dp"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_error_phone_red" />

        <br.com.fs.fslogin.ui.support.views.GothamTextView
            android:id="@+id/error_phone_output"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/two_sp"
            android:textColor="@color/error_login_phone_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/fourteen_sp"
            font:name="@string/font_gotham_medium" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <br.com.fs.fslogin.ui.support.views.GothamButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_sms_login"
        style="@style/AppTheme.RectangularButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/fifty_six_dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_login_vivo_purple"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/btn_login"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/eighteen_sp"
        font:name="@string/font_gotham_bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Changing visibility doesnt change anything. The problem is that it only sets listeners to the first in the framelayout.
For me it's strange to use this pattern of dimens, but its a pattern used in here.